# rounding function in sort keys of jcl

Tags: cobol, mainframe, zos, jcl

i have input record with

```
part - pic x(10), 
country - pic x(03),
department - pic x(07),
year  - pic x(04),
count1 - PIC S9(9) COMP-3,
count2 - PIC S9(9) COMP-3,
count3 - PIC S9(9) COMP-3,
count4 - PIC S9(9) COMP-3,
count5 - PIC S9(9) COMP-3,
USAGE  - PIC S9(5)V9(4) COMP-3,
```

in output record i have to sum up all the counts and then divide it by usage,
if the value after divide is in decimal then need to round of to near value.

after round off then add all the counts for each record at part & model year level. 
means for all the departments if part & year are same i need to make them into one record by summing up count.

please suggest me any solution.

i need to do this in JCL using sort keys only.

Comment: First you have to have a clue as to what JCL is. Have a look at the *JCL Language Reference* for your system. Then realise you can't do it in JCL. SORT has no rounding functions, so you have to code it yourself. What have you tried?

Comment: Your question makes no sense.  You cannot do anything in JCL only and you have a COBOL tag on your question.

Comment: Previous comments are all valid. But also, what should `output record` look like? Before you can work up any coded solution, you have to know what result is expected.